# PDEs - change of variable question

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

We have the following PDE

$$\frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}=0.5\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial \epsilon^2}+(r-0.5\sigma^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon}$$

where U

is a function of $\tau$ and $\epsilon$.

Now if we write $x=\epsilon+(r-0.5\sigma^2)\tau$  and $U=W(x,\tau)$ the book says that we get to

$\frac{\partial W}{\partial \tau}=0.5\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial x^2}$

I couldn't figure out how to get to the transformed PDE. Tried the chain rule for partial derivatives but I didn't get to the correct answer.

Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $r $ and $\sigma$ are constants, we can use the suggested
$$x=\epsilon+(r-0.5\sigma^2)\tau \iff \epsilon = x - (r-0.5\sigma^2)\tau$$
to compute the partial derivatives of $W(x,\tau) := U(\epsilon(x,\tau),\tau)$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} W(x,\tau) &= \frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon} \cdot \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x}\\
&= \frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} W(x,\tau) &= \frac{\partial U^2}{\partial \epsilon^2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} W(x,\tau) &= \frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon} \cdot \frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}\\
&= -(r-0.5\sigma^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon} + \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}
\end{align}

Now, multiplying the first equation by $0.5\sigma^2$ and subtracting the second equation from it:
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow 0.5\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2 W}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial W}{\partial \tau} &= 0.5\sigma^2\frac{\partial U^2}{\partial \epsilon^2} + (r-0.5\sigma^2)\frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon} - \frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}\\
&= 0
\end{align}
The key step here is that the RHS above is equal to zero because of the original PDE. The desired result now follows.

Comment: What has me confused is that $\tau$ can be seen as a function of x as well. Hence, should we have $\frac{\partial U}{\partial \epsilon}.\frac{\partial \epsilon}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial U}{\partial \tau}.\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x}$

Comment: You must choose two out of the three variables $\epsilon, \tau,$ and $x$ to be independent. You start out with $\tau$ and $\epsilon$ as the independent variables, but through the relation $x = x(\tau,\epsilon)$ you're able to choose $x$ and $\tau$ as your new independent variables in the $W(x,\tau)$ PDE. Once you've done that, $\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial x} = 0$.